# "The load fit the truck," "the load fit into the truck" or "the load match the truck"?

Tags: word-usage

Could you please tell me if the following sentences are perfectly natural and mean the same?

> We can deliver it in one go as the load **fit** the truck.
>
> We can deliver it in one go as the load **fit into** the truck.
>
> We can deliver it in one go as the load **match** the truck.

What I'm trying to say is that the truck has enough room to transport the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two choices are correct -- if you mean the past tense

> ✔️  The load **fit the truck.**

This works because "fit" is **past tense**. That means, "we tried it, and it worked".

"To fit" is a tricky verb because it has a past tense ("**I fit. You fit. It fit**") that can look very similar to present tense ("**I fit. You fit.  It fits**.")

If you thought this was **present tense**, see below.

> ✔️ The load **fit into** the truck.

This means almost the same thing.

The difference is: you added "into".  Most people already know that a load goes "into" a truck, so it works with or without this.

Nobody will be confused and wonder if you meant "it fit under" the truck.  You can just say it "fit" the truck.

### This one does not work:

> ☹️ The load *match the truck*.

This one **is not correct**.  The present tense of "match" is "matches", and the past tense is "matched".

### If you meant present tense

You might mean to say one of these:

> ✔️ The load **fits** into the truck.
>
> ✔️ The load **matches** the truck.
>
> ✔️ The load **is** smaller than the truck.

These are present tense.  If you checked the load recently, and it did fit, and nothing has changed, then **present tense** makes sense.

### What's the difference between past and present tense?

For a simple example like this, especially in conversation, present tense or past tense are **both** okay.

In more formal communication, it might be important to clarify when it was checked and whether it was still true.   Suppose you work for NASA.  Then there might be a **big difference** between these two sentences.

> Cargo #123 was checked this morning and it is verified to fit into Shuttle Bay #A1.
>
> Cargo #123 was checked four (4) years ago, and it was verified to fit into Shuttle Bay #A1.

Both of these sentences are grammatically correct, but the difference could lead to a big, billion-dollar mistake.

If it's a conversation between friends, and you're moving some furniture and boxes, the difference between past & present probably doesn't matter.

Comment: In British English the past tense of **fit** is **fitted**.

Comment: Sometimes a load fits _on_ a truck. For example, if you have a car transporter, you don't put cars _into_ your truck but load them _on_ your track.